# Notepad++ RegEX how do I append a character based on start of the character and before a character?

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I would like to append `_OLD` to the end of each strings that starts with `SR_` but before the symbol `'` or without it

For example my text is the following:

```
SR_Apple
When the 'SR_APPLE' rotten, we must discard it.
```

I would like the find and replace to do:

```
SR_Apple_OLD
When the 'SR_APPLE_OLD' rotten, we must discard it.
```

I have tried `(SR_*)+$.*(?='\s)` based on what i Learned but no luck so far. Please help. Thx in Adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple cases you should be able to use

Find: `(\bSR_[\w]+)`

Replace: `$1_OLD`

`(\bSR_.+?)('|$)` and `$1_OLD$2` could also work if the text after SR_ is more complex

The lookbehind you're using is only matching the string if it ends with a ' so it won't find the text not in quotes.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a useful tool for debugging expressions